# Document.ready won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea why this code doesn't work ? I defined a text input field with this ID in the HTML.

```
$('document').ready(function()
{ 
    $('#inputUsername').keyup(alert("something"));
}
);
```

Comment: I would expect the code to work exactly once. well, at least appear to work. You'll get an alert on dom ready without performing a keyup, then you might see an error in the console.

Comment: @KevinB Indeed that's the case as I tested it out in a fiddle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`keyup` takes a function:

```
$('#inputUsername').keyup(function() {
    alert("something")
});
```

Or, define the function before hand:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    alert("something");
}
```

And pass it in:

```
$('#inputUsername').keyup(clickHandler)
```

And unquote `document` -- it's its own variable.

Answer (score 3):

Document is a variable in the browser. You don't need the single quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

Comment: That's true, but not the issue, jQuery figures it out even if it's quoted.

Answer (score 2):

`document` is it's own global variable (standard DOM).

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

You can see this example right on the documentation page
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Your code will try to select an element called document.

```
<document></document>
```

Instead you want to use the global variable called document, or use the shorthand, which is to just pass your handler function directly into the jQuery selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // this runs on DOM ready
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  // this runs on DOM ready
});
```

Comment: In the case of `$('document').ready(...)`, jQuery assumes you were referring to the `document`: http://jsfiddle.net/T5eQs/

Comment: jquery actually ignores whatever was in the `$(...)` portion when you use `.ready` (it will attempt to select it, but it will not be used)

Comment: @JasonP I can't find any documentation to support that, but your fiddle does prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
$('#inputUsername').keyup(alert("something"));
```

.keyup takes a function, **NOT** the above. you can do something like:

```
$('#inputUsername').keyup(function(){alert("something")});
```

It will only call a function ;)